# Creating Queues and retrieving statistics from queues in Opendaylight

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, mininet, openflow, openvswitch

I have created a simple network topology using mininet and integrated it with Opendaylight. Now I want to set up queues on a switch and get the flow stats from it. I haven't found any step by step tutorial anywhere. Any kind of help or suggestions will be appreciated.

[Here is the picture of my network topology attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSYKA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your switches support Openflow 1.3, you can make use of Openflow meter table [1].

Current way to flush a meter to switch with Opendaylight looks like this (full detail in [2]:

1. Create MD-SAL modeled flow and commit it into dataStore using two
   phase commit
2. FRM gets notified and invokes corresponding rpc (addMeter) on particular service provider (if suitable provider for given node registered)
3. the provider (plugin in this case) transforms MD-SAL modeled meter into OF-API modeled meter
4. OF-API modeled meter is then flushed into OFLibrary
5. OFLibrary encodes meter into particular version of wire protocol and sends it to particular switch
6. Check on mininet side if meter is installed

[1] - https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall13/cos597E/papers/openflow-spec-v1.3.2.pdf (Section 5.7)

[2] - https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_OpenFlow_Plugin:End_to_End_Meters#Learn_End_to_End_for_Inventory